# Simple Array Map Issue - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am having a simple problem with my Javascript program. The problem is when I try to map the lengths of nested arrays, the last array is being excluded.

```
// the length doesnt matter, its N number of arrays
var exampleArray = [ [nested array], ..., [nested array] ];

function findArrayLengths() {
  var arrayLengths = exampleArray.map(function(x) {
    return x.length; });
  return arrayLengths; }
```

My question is, is there something obvious I'm missing. Or should this code not in theory produce a new array that contains the lengths of all the nested arrays?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Hypothetical code that doesn't demonstrate the problem doesn't help us answer a question about a bug you're experiencing.

Comment: Even without real code though, shouldn't this hypothetical code produce a new Array containing the lengths of all the nested arrays?

Comment: Luco, yes you're exactly right. That's why it doesn't demonstrate `when I try to map the lengths of nested arrays, the last array is being excluded.`

Comment: I'm not sure how to properly provide a MCVE since I don't know where the problem may be and I can't just dump all my code. I will try though

Comment: Make up a simple example, and see it works. Then make it more looking like your code, step by step. This way you'd know exactly where and why they diverge and would solve your problem yourself :-)

Comment: Try this in console, you can see length of every nested array will be there. `console.log([[1], [1,2], [1,2,3], [1,2,3,4]].map(function(x) { return x.length; }))`

Comment: @LucoP to make this an MCVE, just add some elements to the arrays, and call the function. (However, when I do that, I can't reproduce your problem -- the function works). This suggests that your example doesn't demonstrate your problem. You can use the little `<>` button the editor to make a snippet that runs. You should use it and make a running example that shows the behavior you are seeing.

Comment: Through my efforts to try and make a MCVE, I've realized that my issue is that the array is the flawed part. It is an array of N items but it appears as an array of N-1. for example: an array of 3 things would be (2) [Array(120), Array(341)] but when i expand the array it shows a third item. Thank you all for confirming that the code above should work as intended. This question is technically resolved. I'm gonna go try and figure out why the array isn't being made properly now.

Comment: I will just put it down for the record, I discovered the reason was something strange where since I was calling the function to analyze the array in the same function where I added the array the array wasn't like fully added or something yet so I had to make it so that the array had time to fully add all the elements and then analyze the array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this.
You need to flat the array recursively.

I am considering nested by nested array you mean nested array can be of any depth.

```js
var exampleArray = [ [1,2,3,4], [1,2,[1,2,3]], [1,2,3,4,5,[1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4]]] ];



function findArrayLengths(input) {
  return input.reduce((op,cur)=>{
    return Array.isArray(cur) ? op.concat(findArrayLengths(cur)) : op.concat(cur)
  },[])
}

let op = exampleArray.map(e=>{
  return findArrayLengths(e).length
})

console.log(op);
```

There is one more way of doing it with [Array.prototype.flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). It seems to work fine. ***but will be happy to know if it is good way of doing it or not from any of experienced JS Developer out here on SO.***

```js
var arr = [ [1,2,3,4], [1,2,[1,2,3]], [1,2,3,4,5,[1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4]]], [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,[1,2,3]], [1,2,3,4,5,[1,2,3,4,[1,2,3,4]]]] ];

let op = arr.map(e=> e.flat(Infinity).length);
```

Comment: That's pretty fancy, but there's nothing in the OP's question that suggests the nesting is more than one level — it just looks like an array of arrays.

Comment: @MarkMeyer i considered nested array mean it can be of any depth. recursive will work for all the cases. i have added how to do it with flat also.

Comment: Thanks @CodeManiac those look like they will come in handy in the future. Sadly i discovered the issue was the array was not being made properly so it wasn't the asked about functions fault.